# I can't install osu! on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation

I've been trying to install the game [osu!](http://osu.ppy.sh)  (the not important bit) on my Windows 8 computer, and I've tried every single installer for the game and [.NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=22) and Windows keeps on going: "This app can't run on your PC".

Is there any way to allow third-party programs (even though the .NET installer is by Microsoft themselves) to run on Windows 8? As usual, it runs perfectly fine on Windows 7, or specifically - How should I go about installing "osu!" and ".NET Framework 3.5"?

---

**The not working in Windows 8:**

[image]

**Working fine in Windows 7:**
[image]

**Note:** This question isn't meant for [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) as it's not about the game itself, but the programs/software/runtimes that are required to run it.

Comment: Windows 8.1 comes with .NET Framework 4.5.2 thus any application that requires .NET Framework 3.5 can be ran.  But you can also specifically load .NET Framework 3.5 through the `Add/Remove Windows Features`.  The title does not match the question.  Your question is very specific, saying it can't run anything, isn't specific.

Comment: According to http://osu.ppy.sh/forum/p/1150121 it needs .NET 2.0